# Can I use iScroll to scrollToElement + offset?

Tags: offset, iscroll

I have this code working...

```
myScroller.scrollTo(0, -654, 200);
```

I also have this working....

```
myScroller.scrollToElement("#p4", "1s");
```

Is there a way to add offset to the #id, like scrollToElement("#p4" + 100, "1s")?

Comment: @Layne.. which version have you used for Iscroll. For me myScroller.scrollToElement("#p4", "1s"); is not working. I am using Iscroll Lite version.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't.

```
myScroller.scrollToElement("#p4", "1s");
```

Because first parameter should be the CSS selector of a DOM element. Therefore can you use `"#p4" + 100` for applying CSS rules? If your answer is YES then YOU CAN else YOU CANNOT.

If you wanted to scroll to next element after particular time what you can do is try with `nth-child()` CSS property with a appropriate timeout and incremental flag. Something like this (Assume your elements are inside a parent DIV element which have id **myDiv**)

```
var incre = 0;
function customScrollToElement(){
  myScroller.scrollToElement("#myDiv:nth-child(" + incre + ")", 10);
  incre ++;
}
setTimeout(function(){
  customScrollToElement();
},100);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with some calculation by first using jQuery to get the element's [position](http://api.jquery.com/position/) relative to their parent.

```
var left = -1 * ( $('#p4').position().left + 100 ),
    top  = -1 * ( $('#p4').position().top );
myScroller.scrollTo(left, top, 1000);
```

That will scroll 100 pixels right of the element